# error about stack

Tags: errors

[image: Eccording] to picture why latex give error.thanks

```
\documentclass[11pt]{article}
%\usepackage{xepersian}
%\settextfont{Yas}
%\setdigitfont{Yas}
\begin{document}
\begin{equation}
\sum_{\substack { i \in \cal A \\
i \neq 0} 
}
a_i=b
\end{equation}
\end {document}
```

Comment: The `\substack` command is defined by `amsmath`, so put `\usepackage{amsmath}` before `\begin{document}`.

Comment: Note that `\cal` has been deprecated for more than 20 years. The correct syntax is `\mathcal{A}`.

Answer (score 1):

You are already using `xelatex`. So you can load `unicode-math`:

```
\documentclass[11pt]{article}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\usepackage{unicode-math}
\usepackage{xepersian}
\settextfont{Yas}
\setdigitfont{Yas}
\begin{document}
\begin{equation}
\sum_{\substack { i \in \mscrA \\   i \neq 0}} a_i=b
\end{equation}
\end {document}
```

[image]

`\mscrA`-> medium script A